# How do you prevent screws or other metal from falling in the hole on your router table?

Tags: power-tools, router, router-table

Our community workshop router table also ends up being a work bench much of the time. A router has been broken in the past by someone accidentally knocking a screw in the hole which landed in the router motor housing, then later turning on the router - crunch.

Since then I have used a small wood cutout with a magnet on one side to prevent this happening again, but its difficult to take on and off and is easy to lose.

Basically the goal is to easily/quickly plug the hole, make it removable, and ideally keep the plug from being lost.

Anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: `My router table also ends up being a work bench much of the time.`  I think that's your problem right there, unfortunately.  There's a lot to be said about having a dedicated workbench.

Comment: A picture of your table top opening might help.  Do you have a mounting plate with changeable size insert rings?

Comment: @Ashlar. yes, it's a kreg insert - and i think i may have just seen one that has no hole, which might work. but, if i didn't have that, i suppose it would still be a problem: http://www.woodcraft.com/Product/158286/KREG-690890-Router-Tbl-Insert.aspx?gclid=CMvWn72xjssCFQktaQodOOIBBg

Comment: @grfrazee Good point. And we do have a dedicated work bench or two, but it seems inevitably people do stuff on the router table too.

Comment: My response to that: "you break it, you buy it"  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a blank insert for your router table insert plate - assuming you have one. There is one pictured [in this set of five](http://www.woodcraft.com/Product/158288/KREG-5pc-Router-Insert-Rings.aspx?gclid=CLPYjoevj8sCFY2QHwodJxUPhQ). (shown below)

[image]

[image]